# "Entity does not have a key defined" error in working production code

Tags: entity-framework, silverlight, iis, wcf-ria-services, ria

We are running into a very odd problem: We are using entity framework 4 and ria services for a silverlight 5 appliation hosted in IIS 6.1. For long periods of time, everything is running smoothly, but occasionally the application fails with the following error message in the event log:

> WebHost failed to process a request.
>  Sender Information:
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/56703158
>   Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service
>   '/Services/EcoFleet-DomainServices-Repository-EcofleetRepository.svc'
>   cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.
>  The
>   exception message is: The Entity 'DeviceData' in DomainService
>   'EcofleetRepository' does not have a key defined. Entity types exposed
>   by DomainService operations must have at least one public property
>   marked with the KeyAttribute.. ---> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   The Entity 'DeviceData' in DomainService 'EcofleetRepository' does not
>   have a key defined. Entity types exposed by DomainService operations
>   must have at least one public property marked with the
>   KeyAttribute.
>     at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainServiceDescription.ValidateEntityTypes()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainServiceDescription.Initialize()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainServiceDescription.CreateDescription(Type
>   domainServiceType)
>     at
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory)
>     at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainServiceDescription.GetDescription(Type
>   domainServiceType)
>  at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHost..ctor(Type
>   domainServiceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
>  at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type
>   serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
>  at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String
>   constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
>  at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>  at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo
>   serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>  
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result)  Process Name: w3wp
>   Process ID: 2300

The application still responds, but no entities can be loaded from the server. After stopping and starting the site, everything works again.

The entity in this case (DeviceData) is a database table, and it *does* have a key, and regardless it seems to be random which entity fails. Furthermore I would only expect to see the "key not defined" error at compile time. Does anyone have a clue what the problem is, and how to fix it?

Comment: I hate ria services. But use it. It is very slow at compile time and has many restrictions. If you use a code generator check if `[Key]` is really generating for item. I just use `t4` rarely. EDMX seems better for this kind of issues.

Comment: It isn't generating the attribute, but I still don't understand why it would cause it to only break randomly, only to magically fix itself by restarting the site... However I will try and change the generator, and see if it fixes it.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this problem? We're experiencing the same problem as well.

Comment: @LarsP. I have changed job in the mean time, and I don't recall any more if we found a real fix, or if it just magically fixed itself...

Answer (score 1):

Your `DeviceData` entity do not have key defined, which is required. You should create property with name `Id` or `DeviceDataId` which will be treated as key by convention (Entity Framework currently looks for these properties). Also you can use mappings to set other property as key. This can be achieved with data annotations attributes:

```
[Key]
public int Foo { get; set; }
```

Or with fluent mappings:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DeviceData>().HasKey(d => d.Foo);
```

Comment: The entity does have a key defined already. It is the primary key of the corresponding database table which is a simple int.

Comment: @sondergard what is the name of key? BTW you can't get *key not defined* error in compile time

Comment: public virtual int Id { get; set; }

Comment: I have gotten the "key not defined" at compile time, but that's probably RIA services complaining, not the entity framework. RIA services does require a key on every entity.

Comment: @sondergard that's very strange. Even virtual modifier should not matter here. Try to put `[Key]` attribute manually. Will EF throw error in that case?

Comment: All my entity keys have the virtual keyword, and they are auto generated POCO objects (using a TextTemplatingFileGenerator custom tool). If I put the [Key] attribute, EF will not fail/complain, but it will be removed when updating the POCO entities. However it also does work for long periods of time - several weeks.

Comment: It does lean towards a similar issue I have raised about a "key not defined" error occuring after branching in TFS, for which I have never found a explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833699/no-key-defined-error-on-entity-after-branching-in-tfs.
Maybe there is just something odd happening i RIA services?

Comment: @sondergard unfortunately I haven't used RIA services. From point of EF your code should work just fine. It's very strange issue

Answer (score 0):

First you won't have an error at compile time because it is not a mandatory thing, but not having one might give you quite the headache, because EF use it in many ways. so you have to redefine your key by naming it `Id` or `DeviceDataId`(Using the convention) or define a one from the model.

It seems from your question that there is a key defined for DeviceData, in that case I advice you to relook the properties of the key column in your model.

remember also that not having a key column might reduce the performance of your app.

Comment: There is not much to the properties... It is a mapping to/from an integer primary key column called Id. StoreGeneratedPattern = Identity and EntityKey = true.